# Installing a Python extension from scratch

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Python. I'm familiar with pip... but how do I install something that pip doesn't know about?

Specifically, this is a Jupyter SQL Magics extension ([GitHub link](https://github.com/tkf/ipython-sqlitemagic))

How do I install an extension "from scratch"?

Answer (score 1):

Not everything is uploaded to pip and can be installed by it.

This seems to be a python script not extension.
Just download the code and use it as import to your script.
[Here is how imports work](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Python extensions, modules, library or programs (call them how you like) have setup.py script that makes them install-able. Or if its a program that requires library in order to use it it might have requirements.txt file.
This file is used by pip to install every dependency like so:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

[you can read more about setup.py here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)

Can you give more details what are you trying to accomplish?